# Extensions of groups, Lie algebras etc.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

I was wondering recently about all this theory behind the classification of extensions of algebraic structures like groups, Lie algebras etc. Seems to be a nice question and even better a nice answer what's the possible extensions of a group (Lie Algebras) $G$ by $H$. To do that so, we usually introduce some kind of homological/categorical algebra and we come up with fancy answers containing the 2nd, 3rd cohomology, derivation algebras.

So, a natural question came up in my head; as always there must be a reasonable question behind this rather complicated setup (usually of a more geometric flavor not easily distinguished), hence my question is:

What's the (original) motivation behind the idea of searching the problem of extensions between some kind of algebraic structures?

**P.S.**

If the above question is/seems broad please you can concentrate to groups or Lie algebras. Historical surveys, recommended textbooks or online handouts are more than welcome.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you know that you can break up some structure as an extension of other smaller structures, you can recycle your understanding of the smaller structures to understand stuff about the big structures. It's natural to want to recycle your understanding of things in this way, and wasteful not to try.

Comment: Maybe the theory of *semi-ableian categories* is something you're after: exact sequences hence extensions can be defined there: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category

Comment: Well, the classification of finite groups is exactly the classification of finite simple groups, together with the solution of the extension problem.